# Finding identical values in a list and removing duplicates incorrect output

Tags: python-3.x

I've been working on a function that takes in a list parameter to find identical values while removing duplicates, furthermore processed values would be stored and returned in a new list. I can do this with a for loop in two different ways, however I would like to utilized a while loop as I've done int the code. Upon calling the function, I repeatedly obtain a returned list of [2]. Which baffles me, I have a counter iterating forwards and backwards and searching for identical values and set to remove all duplicates. However, I have repeatedly encountered the [2] after tweaking the code. I will be grateful for some input. Thanks

```
def reverse_dup(my_list):
    new_list = []
    start = 0
    end = len(my_list) - 1
    while start < end:
        if my_list[start] == my_list[end]:
            new_list.append(my_list[start])
            new_list = list(set(new_list))
        start += 1
        end -= 1
    return new_list
```

Comment: To remove duplicates, why not just take `set(my_list)`?

Comment: You only compare the first to the last value, then the second to the next to last, and so on, but this will not necessarily discover all identical values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @wundermahn points out, the easiest "fix" would be:

```
def reverse_dup(my_list):
    return list(set(my_list))
```

I also think that using a `for` loop is more natural, but that is just my opinion. If you are keen on a `while` loop then this works:

```
def reverse_dup(my_list):
    new_list = []
    start = 0
    end = len(my_list) # the -1 not needed since you use start < end
    while start < end:
        ## ----------------------
        ## if the current item is not in the list add it
        ## ----------------------
        if my_list[start] not in new_list:
            new_list.append(my_list[start])
        ## ----------------------
        start += 1 # no need to update end
    return new_list

print(reverse_dup([1,2,1,1,2,3,4,5]))
```

gives you:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code for this purpose:

```
def reverse_dup(lst):
    lst.sort()
    i = len(lst) - 1
    while i > 0:  
        if lst[i] == lst[i - 1]:
            lst.pop(i)
        i -= 1
    return lst
print(reverse_dup([0,1,2,1,1,2,5,0,0,3,4,5]))
```

output:

`[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`